# python 2.7 iterate on list printing subsets of a list

Tags: python-2.7

I have this list: l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] and I would like to iterate on it, printing something like

```
0: [1,2,3,4]
1: [2,3,4,5]
2: [3,4,5,6]
...
n: [17,18,19,20]
```

So far I made this code to print 5 elements at a time, but the last iteration prints 3:

```
for index, item in enumerate(l):
    if index == 0 or index == 1 or index == 2:
        continue
    print index, l[index - 3:index + 2]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Would it help If I propose an easier way? Or do you want to find out a way to do it with the existing logic?

Comment: You can tell the easier way, please. :)

Comment: So the easier way has already been described in the answer. The logic is, " for every index, print the list from 'index' to 'index+sub_len'. And keep printing this until we reach (length_of_list - sub_len)." So If I want to print 5 elements each time the sub_len will be 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track with your list slices. Here's a tweak to make it easier:

```
sub_len = 4
for i in range(len(mylist) - sub_len + 1):
    print l[i:i + sub_len]
```

Where `sub_len` is the desired length of the slices you print.

[demo](https://repl.it/JExg/1)